# Redirect directory with period to query strings in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to have personalized urls, where a person receives a mailer, that has their purl on it, and redirect them to a landing page that receives their name via query string

The url would be like

mywebsite.com/phx/joe.smith

I would like to redirect this traffic to

mywebsite.com/youngstown/index.php?first=joe&last=smith

This should be a 301 redirect, case insensitive. I'm able to do it if the directory was /phx/firstname/lastnaname, but I need it with the dot between first and last rather than a directory.

What I have so far is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^phx\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?  youngstown/index.php?FirstName=$1&LastName=$2 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^phx\/([^\/]+)\/?  youngstown/index.php?FirstName=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to escape slashes `/`. Apart from that, you're almost there. The main difference is `\.` vs `/`, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^phx/(.+?)\.(.+)/?$ youngstown/index.php?first=$1&last=$2 [R,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution could be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phx/([^./]+)\.([^./]+)/?$ /youngstown/index.php?FirstName=$1&LastName=$2 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^phx/([^./]+)/?$ /youngstown/index.php?FirstName=$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

As Olaf says, no need to escape slashes. I am matching here on "not a dot or slash". Also adding `$` to delimit the end of the match and removing `RewriteBase` which is not needed.

**Alternative Solution**

Alternatively you could use a single rule which would set an empty param for `LastName` when not present:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^phx/([^./]+)(?:\.([^./]+))?/?$ /youngstown/index.php?FirstName=$1&LastName=$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```